# Animation is not running for classes with similar name

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I want to do something similar to sample code. I cannot get my animation to run together for similar class name using actual code.

**SAMPLE HTML & CSS CODE**

```css
   

 @keyframes rocket {
    0%   {left:0%; top:0;}
    100% {left:100%; top:0;}
}
@keyframes rocket-to-bottom-right {
    0%   {left:0%; top:0;}
    100% {left:100%; top:500px;}
}

.rocket-animation {
    position: relative;
    animation-name: rocket;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

```html
    

<div class="rocket-animation"><i class="rocket" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="rocket-animation"><i class="rocket" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
</div>
```

**MY ACTUAL CODE**

Animation is not running using my code.

```js
    var topText = document.querySelector(".top-text");
    var btmText = document.querySelector(".btm-text");

    function topSpanGenerator(arrNew) {
      for (i = 0; i < arrNew.length; i++) {
        var span = document.createElement("span"); //To create <span> tags
        span.setAttribute("class", "letter"); //To set class attribute
        topText.appendChild(span); //To put the arrays under .top-text class
        span.innerHTML = arrNew[i]; //To set text for span
      }
    }

    function btmSpanGenerator(arrNew) {
      for (i = 0; i < arrNew.length; i++) {
        var span = document.createElement("span"); //To create <span> tags
        span.setAttribute("class", "letter"); //To set class attribute
        btmText.appendChild(span); //To put the arrays under .top-text class
        span.innerHTML = arrNew[i]; //To set text for span
      }
    }

    // AFTER ANIMATION END, REMOVE SPAN i
    function removeArrayItems() {
      topText.addEventListener("animationend", function(e) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          e.target.remove();
        }, 0.5);
      });

      btmText.addEventListener("animationend", function(e) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          e.target.remove();
        }, 0.5);
      });
    }

    // TOP TEXT GENERATOR
    function topTextGenerator() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        topSpanGenerator(["w", "e", "b", "s", "i", "t", "e"]);
        removeArrayItems();
      }, 500);
      setTimeout(function() {
        topSpanGenerator(["g", "e", "n", "t", "l", "e"]);
        removeArrayItems();
      }, 6000);
      setTimeout(function() {
        topSpanGenerator(["d", "i", "g", "i", "t", "a", "l"]);
        removeArrayItems();
      }, 11500);
      setTimeout(function() {
        topSpanGenerator(["g", "a", "m", "i", "n", "g"]);
        removeArrayItems();
      }, 17000);
    }
    topTextGenerator();

    // BTM TEXT GENERATOR
    function btmTextGenerator() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        btmSpanGenerator(["w", "i", "z", "a", "r", "d", "r", "y"]);
        removeArrayItems();
      }, 800);
      setTimeout(function() {
        btmSpanGenerator(["g", "i", "a", "n", "t"]);
        removeArrayItems();
      }, 6300);
      setTimeout(function() {
        btmSpanGenerator(["o", "v", "e", "r", "l", "o", "r", "d"]);
        removeArrayItems();
      }, 11800);
      setTimeout(function() {
        btmSpanGenerator(["e", "n", "t", "h", "u", "s", "i", "a", "s", "t"]);
        removeArrayItems();
      }, 17300);
    }
    btmTextGenerator();

    // LOOP ANIMATION INFINITE
    function loop() {
      let functionFinish = false;
      if (!functionFinish) {
        setInterval(function() {
          topTextGenerator();
        }, 22000);
      }

      if (!functionFinish) {
        setInterval(function() {
          btmTextGenerator();
        }, 22000);
      }
    }
    loop();
```

```css
    @keyframes fade {
      0% {
        transform: translateY(100px);
        transform: translateZ(2);
        opacity: 0;
      }

      50% {
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
      }

      100% {
        transform: translateY(-100px);
        transform: translateZ(1);
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }

    /* TRICKS IS FOR APPLY FADE ANIMATION */
    .tricks span {
      position: relative;
      animation-delay: 5s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
      -moz-animation-delay: 5s;
      animation: fade 5s cubic-bezier(0.06, 0.83, 0.24, 1) normal;
      -webkit-animation: fade 5s cubic-bezier(0.06, 0.83, 0.24, 1) normal;
      -moz-animation: fade 5s cubic-bezier(0.06, 0.83, 0.24, 1) normal;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      opacity: 0;
    }

    .tricks span:nth-child(0) {
      animation-delay: 0.1s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
      -moz-animation-delay: 0.1s;
    }

    .tricks span:nth-child(1) {
      animation-delay: 0.15s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0.15s;
      -moz-animation-delay: 0.15s;
    }

    .tricks span:nth-child(2) {
      animation-delay: 0.2s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
      -moz-animation-delay: 0.2s;
    }

    .tricks span:nth-child(3) {
      animation-delay: 0.25s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0.25s;
      -moz-animation-delay: 0.25s;
    }

    .tricks span:nth-child(4) {
      animation-delay: 0.3s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
      -moz-animation-delay: 0.3s;
    }

    .tricks span:nth-child(5) {
      animation-delay: 0.35s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0.35s;
      -moz-animation-delay: 0.35s;
    }

    .tricks span:nth-child(6) {
      animation-delay: 0.4s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
      -moz-animation-delay: 0.4s;
    }

    .tricks span:nth-child(7) {
      animation-delay: 0.45s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0.45s;
      -moz-animation-delay: 0.45s;
    }

    .tricks span:nth-child(8) {
      animation-delay: 0.5s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
      -moz-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    }

    .tricks span:nth-child(9) {
      animation-delay: 0.55s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0.55s;
      -moz-animation-delay: 0.55s;
    }

    .tricks span:nth-child(10) {
      animation-delay: 0.6s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
      -moz-animation-delay: 0.6s;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="herowrap">
      <p class="ab__hero-sub">sample text</p>
      <h1 class="top-text tricks"></h1>
      <h1 class="btm-text tricks"></h1>
    </div>


    <div class="parent">
      <div class="herowrap">
        <p class="ab__hero-sub">sample text</p>
        <h1 class="top-text tricks"></h1>
        <h1 class="btm-text tricks"></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I had tried for hours, but is unable to resolve it.
Can anyone tell me why this is happening? Thank you! :

Comment: Amongst other things, the translateZ transform will override the translateY transform.

Comment: I removed the translateZ's, animation still does not work for the "btm-text" class.

Comment: The animation will only work in the child "btm-text" class when I comment out the first "herowrap div". Why is this happening? Shouldn't classes of similar names execute the same function?